# What is affecting my west country lupine's second bloom, and how do I cure it?

Tags: plant-health, container-gardening, lupines

I bought this lupine this Spring when it was in bloom and beautiful, then potted it.  A friend gave me the pot with a plant in it, which I moved.  I’m concerned the pot’s drainage is poor. Could poor drainage cause this whiteness and dead leaves?

In the zoomed in picture, you will see white on the purple flowers.  That stalk is on the left in the zoomed out picture.  Since the right stalk is less effected, is it reasonable to assume that the disease is located on the flowers, not in the whole plant?

The zoomed out picture shows leaves dying while new leaves are growing underneath.

I water daily and fertilize twice a month.  How can I help this beautiful plant?

Thanks!

[image]
[image]